# gdal2xyz Ignore nodata values

Tags: qgis, gdal2xyz

I am trying to export a DEM raster into a xyz file (for later use).

I first clipped the raster in order to limit its extent and the lines in the xyz file.

However, gdal2xyz does not ignore the nodata values (set to 0 here but it is the same with -9999) resulting in a very large .csv files, with most lines with a Z of 0 (useless in my case).

Is it possible and how to ignore those nodata values with gdal2xyz in order to reduce significantly the size of the file?

Comment: As documented https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html GDAL supports only gridded xyz that means that every cell of the raster will be written into the file. It might be easiest to reduce the file size be using some text utility like sed for deleting the lines that you do not need. Such xyz file will be useless for GDAL then.

Comment: @user30184 This is what I am doing (using grep), but I was hoping it was possible to skip the useless calculation time and huge file.

Comment: Computing time must be negligible because there is not much to compute. Big file size is a real issue and xyz a bad choice if that is critical but I guess that you are using some program that cannot handle any more compact file format.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2xyz.html) mention the flag `-skipnodata`. Looks like this was added (under a different name) [in v3.3.0 (December 2020)](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/fb5ac703c7b59dc519657ff24dae593f72def484).

> `-skipnodata`
>
> Exclude the output lines with nodata value (as determined by srcnodata)

Comment: Interesting, but not out yet in my distro!